# GoogleSheets QUERY REGEXREPLACE

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I was able to format a column with zipcode in my query, the problem is that I want to display several other columns, but I don't know how to reference at this point.

I could only display 1 columns, but I want many more

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(P43:P44;"-";""));"Select Col1")
```

I also tried with the substitute:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A43:AD44;SUBSTITUTE(E43:E44;"-";"");"Select *"))
```

Comment: Hey @JhoniRosales were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Comment: Hello Friend.
Great.
I'll test in a few hours and return here

Answer (score 0):

Given the following example table:

[image: example table]

In case you would want to query after removing the `-` characters in the `ZIPCODE` column, you could do it as follows:

```
=QUERY({A:A, ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(B:B, "-", "")), C:D},"Select * WHERE Col4>23")
```

The idea is that using the curly bracket notation you join the multiple ranges you want to query from. Using it, you can apply the `REGEXREPLACE` to the whole `B` Column, and afterwards query from the resulting range.

This is the obtained result with the previous query:

[image: result after query]

Comment: Hello budy, how are you. Good night, I just managed to check it out now. I changed some parameters, tried here for hours. But I can not
What I need is just to format the P: P zip code column and display all columns up to AL. I would be grateful if you give me this tip,

The error is:   " In ARRAY_LITERAL, an array literal does not contain values for one or more lines. "

Comment: the instruction I used was
=QUERY({'⚡Zapier-Woo'!A:AL; ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE('⚡Zapier-Woo'!P:P; "-"; ""));'⚡Zapier-Woo'!A:AL };"Select Col15 ")